# JavaFX 12 maven: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: maven, javafx

I added this vm to my eclipse.ini:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
```

I'm thinking this error has to do with my jdk?

my pom :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>hellofx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontawesomefx</artifactId>
            <version>8.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.openjfx.hellofx.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

this is log :

> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]  [INFO]
>   -------------------------< org.openjfx:market >------------------------- [INFO] Building market 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar
>   ]--------------------------------- [INFO]  [INFO] ---
>   maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ market --- [INFO]
>   Deleting C:\Users\Gabriel\Documents\JavaFxEclipse\market\target [INFO]
>   [INFO] --- javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.3:run (default-cli) @ market ---
>   [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources. [INFO]
>   Copying 2 resources [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
>   [INFO] Compiling 3 source files to
>   C:\Users\Gabriel\Documents\JavaFxEclipse\market\target\classes Error:
>   Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception
>   has occurred. Program will exit. Unrecognized option: --module-path
>   [ERROR] Command execution failed.
>   org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an
>   error: 1 (Exit value: 1)  at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
>     at
>   org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:491)
>     at
>   org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:453)
>     at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:97)     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)    at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
>   org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an
>   error: 1 (Exit value: 1)  at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
>     at
>   org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:491)
>     at
>   org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:453)
>     at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:97)     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)    at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time:  2.887 s [INFO] Finished at:
>   2019-08-07T22:38:55-03:00 [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.3:run (default-cli) on project
>   market: Error: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error:
>   1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack
>   trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run
>   Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR] 
>   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,
>   please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve
It was my system variable
even being on sk12

she was below

```
C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Common Files \ Oracle \ Java \ javapath

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin
```

i make this:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin
C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Common Files \ Oracle \ Java \ javapath
```